# sed doesn't exit, even though it is done

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to manipulate a text file. I've got most of it figured out myself, but I'm stumped with why sed seems to go into infinite loop mode. The text file can be downloaded from [census.gov](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/ansi/national.txt).

At the moment, I just want a list of states that I can throw into a for loop to do some state-specific processing. So far, I've got this. (I'm not a bash expert, suggestions are welcome.

```
sed 1d tables/ansi.csv | awk -F "," '{print $1}' | uniq | tr \n : | sed s/:/" "/g
```

I want to put this into $() to use the output in a for loop, but for some reason, sed is hanging up and not exiting. I actually need to add a couple of things to the final sed command, to properly format things, but I want to get this running correctly before I go any further.

In the end - I want something that looks like (just showing the first few):

```
"AL" "AK" "AZ" "AR" "CA" "CO" ....
```

Right now, sed returns more of less what I expect and returns (just showing the last few)

```
...."MP" "PR" "UM" "VI" "
```

But, rather than exiting, sed hangs and I have to Ctrl-C out of the script. If I remove the final sed statement, the little script runs as I would expect, without hanging.

So, why on earth is this hanging?

Comment: FWIW, your command works fine on OSX.  I can't quite tell what version of sed that has though as `sed --version` doesn't work here.

Comment: @whaley - It's interesting that it works on OSX, but not Ubuntu. I guess the BSD user-land utilities are slightly different. I'm curious, does the awk statement posted below (which I accepted as the answer) work on OSX?

Comment: Yes, the entire command works, I downloaded that csv file and tried it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest putting the `sed` script inside quotes:

```
sed 1d tables/ansi.csv | awk -F "," '{print $1}' | uniq | tr '\n' : | sed 's/:/" "/g'
```

The reason that `sed` seems to "hang" may be that `tr` has removed the final newline which `sed` requires. By the way, the newline argument to `tr` needs to be quoted.

However, the whole thing can be done in AWK:

```
awk -F, 'NR > 1 {a[$1]=$1} END { delim=":"; num=asort(a); for (i=1;i<=num;i++) printf "\"%s\" ",a[i]; printf "\n"}' tables/ansi.csv
```

Comment: Thanks. The awk statement works perfectly. I really need to spend some time learning more awk. The quotations got removed from the sed statement accidentally. They were there and then I deleted the whole thing, trying to figure out the problem and I just forgot to put them back in.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"," 'NR>1 && (!($1 in a)){print $1;a[$1]}' file|sort|awk '{printf "\"%s\" ",$1}'
```